# Dynamically allocated C-style string has more characters than given length?

Tags: c++, arrays, file, c-strings

I'm using a dynamic C-style string to read in data from a file, but for some reason when I dynamically allocate the C-style string using the given length, it comes out with four extra characters that can be seen using `strlen()`. The junk in these empty spaces is added on to the end of the read-in string and is displayed on `cout`. What on earth could be causing this, and how can I fix it?

The C-style string is declared in the beginning of the code, and is used one time before this. The time it is used before this it is also too large, but in that case it does not add extra information to the end. After use, it is deleted and not used again until this point. I'm pretty confused as I have not had this happen or had a problem with it before.

```
// Length read as 14, which is correct
iFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&length), sizeof(int)); 

tempCstring = new char[length]; // Length still 14
cout << strlen(tempCstring); // Console output: 18

// In tempCstring: Powerful Blockýýýý
iFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(tempCstring), length);

// Custom String class takes in value Powerful Blockýýýý and is 
// initialized to that
tempString = String(tempCstring);

// Temp character value takes in messed up string
temp.setSpecial(tempString); 
delete[] tempCstring; // Temp cString is deleted for next use
```

When written to file:

```
// Length set to the length of the cString, m_special
length = strlen(chars[i].getSpecial().getStr());

// Length written to file. (Should I add 1 for null terminator?)
cFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&length), sizeof(int));

// String written to file
cFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(chars[i].getSpecial().getStr()), length);
```

Comment: You need `length + 1` to allow for the null terminator, and you actually have to null terminate it.

Comment: Unrelated: Careful with the term CString. [There is a widely used class with that name.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174288.aspx) I've taken to calling null-terminated character arrays c-strings to prevent confusion and because I'm too damn lazy to type null-terminated character array over and over.

Comment: `iFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&length), sizeof(int));` what does this do exactly, considering `length` is an `int`?

Comment: @KillzoneKid it reads `sizeof(int)` number of bytes from the file and stores them in `length`.  The type-cast is required because `read()` expects a `char*` pointer, even when reading binary data

Comment: @empoweredev on a side note, when writing a string to file, you should call `getStr()` one time and cache the value to a local variable, then you can use that variable when calculating `length` and calling `write()`. And NO, you should not add +1 for the null terminator when writing `length` to the file (unless you are actually writing the null terminator to file).

Comment: @RemyLebeau So the bytes it reads are the `int` that is used later to define the length of the string, I gotcha

Comment: @KillzoneKid the code stores strings in the file in `<length><chars>` format, ie writing the `length` then writing the characters, and so when reading a string, it reads the `length` then reads the characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you see junk at the end of a string, the problem is almost always the lack of a terminator. Every C-style string ends in a byte whose value is zero, spelled `'\0'`. If you did not place one yourself, the standard library keeps reading bytes in memory until it sees a random `'\0'` that it sees in memory. In other words, the array is read beyond its bounds.

Use `memset(tempCString,0,length)` in order to zero out the memory following your allocation. However, this is not the soundest solution, as it is covering the real problem under the rug. Show us the context in which this code is used. Then I will be able to say where in your algorithm you will need to insert the null terminator: `tempCString[i] = 0`, or something like that. Nonetheless, from what you have posted, I can tell that you need to allocate one more character to make room for the terminator.

Also, since you are using C++, why not use `std::string`? It avoids these kinds of problems.

Comment: Ah man, now I feel dumb. I didn't think the null terminator was the issue because it was making a cstring longer than the value that I sent in. I fixed it in my file read so that one is added to the length and the null terminator is put in the empty space and it works fine now. Thank you very much for helping me out sir! As for why I am not using string, this is a school project and I was required to write my own string class to use. I'm assuming this means I shouldn't use the built in string class, so I've just been using cStrings. Would definitely make it easier though.

Comment: @empoweredev you've been given power. So much that you're free to shoot yourself in the foot. How those toes feelin? ; )

Comment: As I recall, C++ was intended to make it harder [to shoot yourself in the foot...](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#really-say-that)